# Does Father Joseph take a wound if Strength of Spirit fails?

Tags: last-night-on-earth

Father Joseph has the Strength of Spirit ability:

> take a wound to cancel any Zombie Card on the roll of 3+

Does this mean that Father Joseph only takes a wound if the roll is successful, or does he still take a wound if the roll fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Father Joseph takes the wound first, and then rolls to try and cancel the Zombie card.

From [the FAQ, here](http://www.flyingfrogwiki.com/ffpwiki/index.php?title=Ability%3aStrength_of_Spirit):

> Q11: How does Father Joseph’s Strength of Spirit ability work?
>
> A11: Strength of Spirit may be used at any time to attempt to Cancel a
>   Zombie Card being played or that ‘Remains in Play’. Father Joseph
>   first takes a wound and then rolls to cancel the Zombie Card on the
>   roll of 3+. He may use this ability even if doing so will take his
>   last wound, killing him (you are still allowed to roll to see if the
>   card is cancelled). He may also use this ability multiple times to try
>   and cancel the same card (assuming he failed the first time by rolling
>   a 1 or 2). He may even use this ability during a Fight. This is
>   especially useful if he is about to lose a Fight and take his last
>   wound. He may instead, voluntarily take his last wound to try and
>   cancel an existing Zombie Card (sort of a ‘with his last breath’
>   notion).